# How to position the child views in multiple positions in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a login page which has three fields and a button at the center of the page. At the Bottom of the same page, I need to display a three buttons in a vertically. How can I do this in Flutter? Any suggestions would be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, I think you need to place 3 buttons at the bottom of a column.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 25.0, bottom: 25.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Text Field 1'),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Text Field 2'),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Text Field 3'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25.0,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Button'),
              color: Colors.blue,
              minWidth: double.infinity,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Button 1'),
              color: Colors.blue,
              minWidth: double.infinity,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Button 2'),
              color: Colors.blue,
              minWidth: double.infinity,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Button 3'),
              color: Colors.blue,
              minWidth: double.infinity,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

`Expanded` will fill the empty space

result will be like,
[image]

If your question is different, give me more details

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to display the first three fields and a button at the center of the page and a column with three buttons at the bottom of the page. How should I do that? If I use expanded for the bottom set of buttons my center align fields moved to the start of the page.

Comment: @Arvind I have added another answer try out that

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Stack` and `Positioned` to achieve what you want, Check the example below

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 25.0, bottom: 25.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Text Field 1'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Text Field 2'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Text Field 3'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.0,
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Button'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  minWidth: double.infinity,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 1'),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 2'),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Button 3'),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps. You saved my day. I have been trying this without positioned widget so far.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputations. So, even though I accept it, answer is not displayed as accepted.

Comment: @Arvind That's okay mate